# Cant accept call in quickblox for android

Tags: android, quickblox, android-audiomanager

*I'm having problem when accept call from receive new session.*

My Code:

```
public void onReceiveNewSession(QBRTCSession session) {
       // session = currentSession;

       userInfo = session.getUserInfo();

        userInfo = new HashMap<String,String>();
        userInfo.put("key", "value");
        session.acceptCall(userInfo);
```

Output:

```
Could not find method android.media.AudioManager.isVolumeFixed, referenced from method org.webrtc.voiceengine.WebRtcAudioTrack.SetStreamVolume

VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 739: Landroid/media/AudioManager;.isVolumeFixed ()Z
```

Comment: Please specify SDK version used and provide the full log. Additionally specify the device and Android version on it.